# How to order by various values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sorting

Example:

```
----------------------------------------------
P.No     |     Relation   |  Name 
----------------------------------------------
2        |     Self       | Kumar
----------------------------------------------
1        |     Husband    | Selvam
----------------------------------------------
2        |     Son        |  Manoj
----------------------------------------------
1        |    Self        |   Gandhi
----------------------------------------------
```

How can I  the rows based on column values preference?

I want something like this:

```
Order By P.No & 
 ( Self 1 st preference ,  
   Husband 2nd preference,
   son 3rd Preference )
```

And I'm expecting this output:

```
----------------------------------------------
P.No     |     Relation   |  Name 
----------------------------------------------
1        |      Self       |   Gandhi
----------------------------------------------
1        |     Husband    | Selvam
----------------------------------------------
2        |     Self       | Kumar
----------------------------------------------
2        |     Son        |  Manoj
----------------------------------------------
```

Please help me resolve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Actually P.No Order is ok,. But i need to give preference for second order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could probably do something like:

```
order by p.`No`, `Relation`='Self', `Relation`='Husband', `Relation`='Son'
```

The expressions `Relation='Self'`, `Relation='Husband'`, `Relation='Son'` return `0` or `1` (in the order added) depending if satisfied or not. Thus can generate the needed ordering

You can also use the [FIELD function of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) as:

```
order by p.`No` ASC, FIELD(`Relation`,'Self,Husband,Son') ASC
```

Comment: Very Thank you @RamRaider

Comment: Welcome - and thanks to @Nikos M for adding more detail

Answer (score 5):

You want to translate The triple `(Self, Husband, Son)` into something, that is compareable. There are a few ways to do that:

The naive way:

```
ORDER BY IF(Relation="Self",0,IF(Relation="Husband",1,2))
```

Or the funky way:

```
ORDER BY (Relation="Self")+2*(Relation="Husband")+3*(Relation="Son")
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try below query

```
select *,if(Relation = 'Self',1,if(Relation = 'Husband',2,if(Relation = 'Son',3,4))) as rel_ord from table order by p.No asc ,rel_ord asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just list them in order of preference.

```
ORDER BY P.No,Name,Relation ASC
```